# Unable to get div to animate from left to right in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-animate

I have a list which serves as a menu. Every time user clicks on one of the elements in the list, I want a more detailed `div` to slide in from left to right.

So if the user was to click menu item `A` first, `A` slides from left to right. If the user then clicks `B`, `A` slides out from right to left (disappears off screen) and `B` slides in.

I searched for this problem and found this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7369370/how-to-make-div-move-right-and-left-using-jquery-animate-method). I incorporated the code from the `jsfiddle`, but it didn't work. No errors are being shown in the js log in Chrome debugging tool. Nothing happens when I click any item from the menu. What am I doing wrong?

```
 <div class="project">
        <ul id="project_menu" class="project_menu">
            <li id="menu-php-mysql" data-projectID="php-project">PHP/MySQL</li>
            <li id="menu-nodejs" data-projectID="node-project">NodeJS</li> 
            <!-- more code -->
        </ul>
        <div class="project-detail">
            <div id="php-project">
                <i class="ion-ios-close-empty close-icon js-close-icon"></i>
                <div classs="project-text">
                    <!-- data about project -->
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="node-project">
                <i class="ion-ios-close-empty close-icon js-close-icon"></i>
                <div classs="project-text">
                    <!-- data about project -->
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- and so on.. -->
```

```css
#php-project {
    background-color: #9b59b6;
    margin: 30px;
    display: none;
}

$(document).ready(function() {

    itemsToRender = [];

    $('ul#project_menu li').click(function(e) {

        menuItemId = (e.currentTarget.id);

        $('.common').hide();

        $(getProjectId(menuItemId)).css('display', 'inline');

        var value = $(getProjectId(menuItemId)).css('right') === '100px' ? '-100px' : '100px';
        $(getProjectId(menuItemId)).animate({
            right: value                
        }, 800);

    });
});

function getProjectId(menuItemId) {

    if (menuItemId.indexOf('php') > 0) {

        return '#php-project';

    } else if (menuItemId.indexOf('node') > 0) {

        return '#node-project';

    } else if (menuItemId.indexOf('angular') > 0) {

        return '#angular-project';

    } else if (menuItemId.indexOf('mean') > 0) {

        return '#mean-project';

    }          
}
```

**Update1**: [@user5325596](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5325596/user5325596) pointed out that my display property for the detail `div` was set to none, so I fixed that by adding the following:

```
$(getProjectId(menuItemId)).css('display', 'inline-block');
```

right after `$('.common').hide()`.

Now, I can see the detail div when I click on the menu item, but it does not animate.

**Update2**: I have uploaded a [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/creature_x/tvpk4vpa/), it includes the jquery animation that I am successfully using (fadeIn, which is commented out), as well as the code suggested by elchininet.

Comment: In your css you have `display:none`, does that ever get changed?

Comment: Thank you for your comment! I updated the post to reflect your suggestion.

Comment: do you have an example? image, jsfiddle?

Comment: you can't move an `inline` element.

Comment: @DanielA.White, you mean it is not possible to animate `inline` displayed elements? https://jsfiddle.net/Mi_Creativity/cp064nxw/

Comment: @Mi-Creativity not with the `right` property.

Comment: Here's the `right` https://jsfiddle.net/Mi_Creativity/a3k9zbo3/

Comment: @Frosty619 check my answer is that hat you're asking for?

Comment: I will look at it next (:

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you need or not

[**JS Fiddle** - *updated 2*](https://jsfiddle.net/Mi_Creativity/zfkLvvjz/)

```js
// initializing
var prevID = '',
    divs = $('.sliding-divs');

$("li").on("click", function() {
  var theID, theDiv, theDivW, theCenter;
  
  // get the id letter from the li, then pick the corresponding sliding
  // div depending on its value.
  theID = $(this).attr('id');
  theID = theID.replace('li-', '');
  theDiv = $('#div-' + theID);
  
  // get the divs width to slide it into the center of the view
  theDivW = theDiv.width();
  theCenter = $(window).width()/2 - theDivW/2;
  
  // if the user didn't click the link which its slide already 
  // in the view, this to avoid sliding out and in same div.
  if(theID != prevID){
      if (prevID == '') {
    
      // if we don't have a previously slided in div, we just slide 
      // the just click link's div into the view
      theDiv.animate({'left': theCenter}, 1000);
    } else {
     
      // animated the previous div to the right out of the view, then
      // move all divs to their original position out from the left
      // this is because if we don't do this, an already slided div 
      // will later be slided in from right instead in from left
      // because we have already changed its position.
      // slide the just clicked link's div into the view from left
      $('#div-' + prevID).animate({'left': '110%'}, 800);
      divs.css({'left':-(theDivW + 100)});
      theDiv.animate({'left': theCenter}, 1000);
    }
  }

  // change the value of the id representing previously slided in div
  prevID = theID;
});
```

```css
body {
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
}

li {
  width: 100px;
  height: 25px;
  margin: 2px 0;
  color: white;
  padding: 3px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: green;
  cursor:pointer;
}

.sliding-divs {
  position: absolute;
  width: 500px;
  line-height: 250px;
  background-color: orange;
  font-size: 30px;
  border: 2px gold solid;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  top: 150px;
  left: -510px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li id="li-A">item 1</li>
  <li id="li-B">item 2</li>
  <li id="li-C">item 3</li>
  <li id="li-D">item 4</li>
</ul>
<div class="sliding-divs" id="div-A">
  DIV A
</div>
<div class="sliding-divs" id="div-B">
  DIV B
</div>
<div class="sliding-divs" id="div-C">
  DIV C
</div>
<div class="sliding-divs" id="div-D">
  DIV D
</div>
```

Comment: I tried incorporating your code, but I am stuck because the divs are not aligned properly, so the detail div are still there, on the left side of the screen. Please see the image below:
http://imgur.com/dEMbwQC

I have posted a jsFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/creature_x/vsd76x0c/

Comment: First it looks like your `.sliding-div` is too wide that some part of its left appears *behind* the menu buttons, Second it'd be much helpful if you could create a fiddle identical to your situation with full css.

Comment: I looked at your code and tried to incorporate it, but it didn't work. Here is the JS fiddle:  https://jsfiddle.net/creature_x/fbyf4nfn/. I think I need more coffee.

Comment: OK, I figured it out. Thanks (:

Answer (score 3):

Try with `CSS` transitions, will save a lot of code. Maybe this is not exactly that you want but I'm sure it'll helps you with your task.

**HTML Code**

```
<ul>
  <li>One</li>
  <li>Two</li>
  <li>Three</li>
  <li>Four</li>
  <li>Five</li>
</ul>
```

**CSS Code**

```
li{
  -webkit-transition: all 1s;
  -moz-transition: all 1s;
  transition: all 1s;
}

li.open{
  -webkit-transform: translateX(100px);
  -moz-transform: translateX(100px);
  transform: translateX(100px);
}
```

**jQuery Code**

```
$("li").on("click", function(){

    $("li.open").removeClass("open");

    $(this).addClass("open");

});
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/elchininet/5rurh2n8/)

Here you have a `jsfiddle` with your code modified and the div animations in [css](/questions/tagged/css).

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/elchininet/10Lb8wwg/) with part of your code.

Comment: Be sure to put the non-prefixed properties *before* the prefixed versions. See also [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12528398/ordering-in-vendor-based-css3-vs-standard-css3-syntax#12531574)

Comment: Thanks @StevenDon. That is a practice that I never did. Every day I learn a new thing, I'll fix that. But the comment says exactly the opposite that you said ;)

Comment: Hi, I tried incorporating your code, but the same problem: when I click the menu item, the div does not appear. I am not getting any errors in the dev console. I have uploaded a js fiddle with your code in it, please have a look at the post update (:

Comment: Hi @Frosty619, I'll try to understand your code and I'll make an example. Give me a time.

Comment: Take a look at may last jsfiddle. I don't know if it is that you want.

Comment: Well, @elchininet, it actually does say `The reason why you should declare the unprefixed property last is ...` then giving the reason for it, but does so in a rather roundabout way (and by quoting the question, which has it reversed).

Comment: Don't worry mate. I've understood your comment and I've learned a new thing ;)

Comment: Ah yeah, I mixed up my own before/after. Oh well, can't edit that any more. Glad to see you got it correct :)

Answer (score 0):

There are some minor mistakes i found on fiddle like , comma between class name. : `class="project-container,common"`

You are hiding all `div` with `class` `.common`, but not show it after. so its `style` property get `display:none` even if you add `class` `open` to that `div`.

**Here is my Updated and running code:**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
   
    itemsToRender = [];
    $('ul#project_menu li').click(function(e) {
       
        
         
        $('.common').hide();
        menuItemId = (e.currentTarget.id);
        var projectId = getProjectId(menuItemId);
        console.log(projectId);
        
        $('.project-container.open').removeClass('open');
        $(projectId).addClass('open');
        $(projectId).show();
        
        
       /* $(projectId).fadeIn('slow'); <--- THIS WORKS! But I want the slide effect instead  */
       });
       
  
  function getProjectId(menuItemId) {
    
    if (menuItemId.indexOf('php') > 0) { 
        return '#php-project';
    
    } else if (menuItemId.indexOf('node') > 0) {
        return '#node-project';
     
    } else if (menuItemId.indexOf('angular') > 0) {
        return '#angular-project';
     
    } else if (menuItemId.indexOf('mean') > 0) {
        return '#mean-project';
     
    }  else if (menuItemId.indexOf('html5-css3-js') > 0) {
        return '#html-css-js-project';
     
    }          
}
       
       
 });
```

```css
.project-detail {
    
    float: right;
    max-width: 50%;
    margin-right: 75px;
    color: #fff; 
}

#php-project {
   background-color:#9b59b6;
    margin: 30px;
    display:none;

}
#node-project {
   background-color:#27ae60;
    margin: 30px;
    display:none;
}

.project-container{
  transition: all 1s;
  -webkit-transition: all 1s;
  -moz-transition: all 1s;
}

.project-container.open{
  transform: translateX(-200px);
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-200px);
  -moz-transform: translateX(-200px);
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="project">
                
                 <ul id="project_menu" class="project_menu">
                     
                    <li id="menu-php-mysql" data-projectID="php-project">PHP/MySQL</li>
                    <li id="menu-nodejs" data-projectID="node-project">NodeJS</li> 
                
                </ul>
                
                <div class="project-detail">
                
                    <div id="php-project" class="project-container  common">
                      <i class="ion-ios-close-empty close-icon js-close-icon"></i>
                    
                    <div classs="project-text">
                         
                         <h2 class="project-label">Project title: <span class="project-name"> php project</span></h2>         
                     </div> 
                  </div> <!-- end of php-project -->
                  
                  
                  <div id="node-project" class="project-container  common">
                      <i class="ion-ios-close-empty close-icon js-close-icon"></i>
                    
                    <div classs="project-text">
                         
                         <h2 class="project-label">Project title: <span class="project-name"> node project</span></h2>         
                     </div> 
                  </div> <!-- end of node-project -->
                  
                  
                  
              </div> <!-- end of project-detail -->
          </div>    <!-- end of project  -->
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want this to work like in this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9hxb8bLt/)

HTML Code

```
  <div class="project">
  <ul id="project_menu" class="project_menu">
    <li id="menu-php-mysql" data-projectID="php-project">PHP/MySQL</li>
    <li id="menu-nodejs" data-projectID="node-project">NodeJS</li>
    <!-- more code -->
  </ul>
  <div class="project-detail">
    <div id="php-project">
      <i class="ion-ios-close-empty close-icon js-close-icon"></i>
      <div classs="project-text">
        PHP project text
        <!-- data about project -->
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="node-project">
      <i class="ion-ios-close-empty close-icon js-close-icon"></i>
      <div classs="project-text">
        Node Project Text
        <!-- data about project -->
      </div>
      <!-- and so on.. -->
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS Code

```
.project_menu > li{
  cursor: pointer;
}
.project-detail{
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #dedede;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}
```

JQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('.project-detail > div:first-child').css("right","0px");
  itemsToRender = [];
  $('#project_menu li').click(function(e) {
        menuItemId = (e.currentTarget.id);

    $('.common').hide();

    $(getProjectId(menuItemId)).css('display', 'inline');
    var value = '0px';
    $(getProjectId(menuItemId)).animate({
      right: '0px'

    }, 800);
    var req = '.project-detail > div';
    $('.project-detail > div').not($(getProjectId(menuItemId))).animate({
        right: '300px'
    }, 800);

  });
});

function getProjectId(menuItemId) {

  if (menuItemId.indexOf('php') > 0) {
    return '#php-project';

  } else if (menuItemId.indexOf('node') > 0) {
    return '#node-project';

  } else if (menuItemId.indexOf('angular') > 0) {
    return '#angular-project';

  } else if (menuItemId.indexOf('mean') > 0) {
    return '#mean-project';

  }
}
```